# How do I exctract Json Data swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, fetch-api

Hello i have been working with youtube api and i fetch the api that looks like this, i have managed to fetch title and description by using decoder my structure on how to i did that is below

```
`{
kind: "youtube#videoListResponse",
etag: "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/afeay36Ls6JJ-W_ngFTxbc2s6Pw\"",
pageInfo: {
totalResults: 1,
resultsPerPage: 1
},
items: [
{
kind: "youtube#video",
etag: "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/6vv0LQwRyqqns6JEgC-Gg86wBZk\"",
id: "7lCDEYXw3mM",
snippet: {
publishedAt: "2012-06-20T23:12:38.000Z",
channelId: "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
title: "Google I/O 101: Q&amp;A On Using Google APIs",
description: "Antonio Fuentes speaks to us and takes questions on working with Google APIs and OAuth 2.0.",
`
```

Here is my structure

```
struct Videos: Decodable {
            let items: [item]

        }

        struct item: Decodable {
            let snippet: snippet
        }

        struct snippet: Decodable {
            let title: String
            let description: String
            let thumbnails: thumbnails

        }

        struct thumbnails: Decodable {
            let `default`: defal
        }

        struct defal: Decodable {
            let url: String
        }
```

here is how i fetched i used URLSession i didn't include all the fetch code because it will be to much, but still as you can see that i have printed title by using an for statement and that works great because in terminal I can see the title.

```
        guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let data = try decoder.decode(Videos.self, from: data)


                for item in data.items {
                    guard let title: String = item.snippet.title else { return }

                    print(title)
                }
```

I want my cell to use the title that i declared earlier however when i try to do that the title is suddenly nil, but inside the fetch block it has the value I'm looking for.

```
        print(title)
        cell.textLabel?.text = title
```

my question is how do i extract the title and description and all that stuff so later my cell can use it and i'm unsure if my fetch structure i'm using is correct any find feedback on the structure and how to extract the data so my cell can use it is very helpful and I appreciate it very much

Comment: let title = data["items"]["title"]

Comment: I doubt that the `guard` line compiles because all objects are non-optional. And please conform to the naming convention that struct names start with a capital letter. The solution is most likely related to asynchronous data processing and then not related to the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct item: Codable {

        let publishedAt: String
        let channelId: String
        let title: String
        let description: Int

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case publishedAt = "publishedAt"
            case channelId = "channelId"
            case title = "title"
            case description = "description"
        }
    }


    struct Videos: Decodable {

        let results: [item]

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case results = "items"

        }
    }

    // for parsing 
     let itemsArray =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Videos.self, from: json.rawData(options: .prettyPrinted))

 // in cell for row

let title = itemsArray[indexPath.row].title
```